# How to call a function in bash_profile into a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a function in `.bash_profile`

```
certspotter(){
curl -s https://certspotter.com/api/v0/certs\?domain\=$1 | jq '.[].dns_names[]' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u | grep $1
}
```

and i am trying to call that function in a bash script `test.sh`

But getting error like below

`test.sh: 4: test.sh: certspotter: not found`

Any way to call that in that script

Comment: Source the script instead of executing.

Comment: What does `test.sh` contain? How exactly are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the function where it is defined (in .bash_profile)

```
export -f certspotter
```

Comment: tried this not working

Answer (score -1):

It seems there are two issues here. First, defining a function requires the `function` keyword, at least on my system, thus the function definition should be:

```
function certspotter(){
    curl -s https://certspotter.com/api/v0/certs\?domain\=$1 | jq '.[].dns_names[]' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u | grep $1
}
```

Then, as mentioned in the comments, the script calling the function needs to source the file containing the function. As you currently have things set up, it would be:

```
. .bash_profile
```

However, you may want to give some thought as to whether you want to call your .bash_profile just to get the function imported. Instead, you may want to create a separate script file for your library of functions.